# Why I can't call a member function inside ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have:

```
export class Foo {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    public formatName() : string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let foo of allFoos">
    <strong>{{foo.formatName()}}</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Why this doesn't work? I'll just get `node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3076 TypeError: self.context.$implicit.formatName is not a function`

I can work around this by moving the `formatName()` function to the parent Component and give `foo` as an argument instead of using `this`, but it's not what I want:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let foo of allFoos">
    <strong>{{formatName(foo)}}</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Accessing e.g. foo.name directly in the loop also works just fine:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let foo of allFoos">
    <strong>{{foo.name}}</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously my intention is to have a much more complex `formatName()` than the one in my example.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker? It's quite cumbersome to reason about what part of your code is part of what component and how they are related.

Comment: Or better yet, a Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button) here on-site.

Comment: where is allFoos defined. If this template corresponds to the Foo component, then the Foo must have a **private allFoos:Foo[];**

Comment: I added a notion that accessing e.g. foo.name in the loop works just fine. It's just the member function that cannot be called. If I console.log the foo object from ngFor it seems that the member function is indeed missing. Only the properties are there.

Comment: My application is as simple as it gets, just like the Angular 2 Tutorial app. One Component that includes an array of Foos, the template and Foo defined in a separate file.

Comment: It's still not obvious. That several people ask already is a strong indication. Otherwise try https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Functions/Methods should almost never be called in `{{}}` because Angular2 will update those statements on every changeEvent.

Better format your name on init or whenever you need to format it, in your component class and only use the property name for {{}}